# Play Framework. Accepting JSON and Form Submit on same action

Tags: scala, playframework, typesafe-activator

I have written this sample Application using Play Scala framework. (TypeSafe Activator)

### Application.scala

```
package controllers

import play.api.mvc._
import models._


object Application extends Controller {

  def index = Action {
        Ok(views.html.main(Person.form))
  }

  def submit = Action { implicit request =>
    Person.form.bindFromRequest().fold(
            formWithErrors => BadRequest(views.html.main(formWithErrors)),
            p => {
                Ok(s"Hi ${p.firstname} ${p.lastname}")
            }
        )
  }
}
```

### Person.scala

```
package models

import play.api.data.Form
import play.api.data.Forms.{mapping, text, of}
import play.api.data.format.Formats.doubleFormat
import play.api.libs.json.{__, Reads, Writes}
import play.api.libs.functional.syntax._
import play.api.libs.json.Json

case class Person(firstname: String, lastname: String)

object Person {
    val form = Form(mapping(
          "firstname" -> text,
          "lastname" -> text
        )(Person.apply)(Person.unapply))

  implicit val readsPerson: Reads[Person] = (
    ((__ \ "firstname").read[String]) and
    ((__ \ "lastname").read[String])
  )(Person.apply _)  

  implicit val writesItem = Writes[Person] {
    case Person(firstname, lastname) =>
      Json.obj(
        "firstname" -> firstname,
        "lastname" -> lastname
      )
  }  
}
```

Now this works wonderfully from the browser.

However when I try to invoke the action from curl

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -X POST -d '{"firstname":"abhishek", "lastname":"srivastava"}' http://localhost:9000/
```

It fails with a lengthy HTML message.

My understanding was that if I use x-www-form-urlencoded, then at the time of post, I can accept requests both from the HTML form as well as a JSON request.

Am I doing something wrong? or is my understanding flawed?

Basically I want the same controller method Action to service the json post request as well as the html form submission.

Comment: I don't think you can send it as json, but need to -d 'firstname=abhishek&lastname=srivastava'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: set the `Content-Type` header on the client side, use the default body parser on the server side, and it'll all work just like magic! :)  Replace `Action(parse.urlFormEncoded)` with simply `Action` which'll then use the default parser.

Long answer:

The default parser will automatically use the correct parser based on the `Content-Type` header, whether it's `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, `application/json` and some more.

Then in your `post` method, `bindFromRequest` will then examine all bodies determining which one has been set, whether it's `asFormUrlEncoded` or `asJson`, then use it for form data handling.

Comment: thanks. it makes sense and I removed the parse.urlFormEncoded. I also added the json serialization deserialization logic but still I got the lengthy HTML error. I have edited my code above to its current state.

Comment: The lengthy HTML would be Page's error page with details (only in development mode ;)) re the problem, can you paste in what the problem was, you can find the error/stacktrace in the console also.

Comment: Your suggestion worked. My request was wrong. the request which I was sending was `curl -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -X POST -d '{"firstname":"abhishek", "lastname":"srivastava"}' http://localhost:9000/` but what I should use is `curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"firstname":"abhishek", "lastname":"srivastava"}' http://localhost:9000/`. So I was sending json but saying its x-www